# Algebra generated by a function and uniform limits

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

We take $f: [ \alpha, \beta ] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. We consider $E = \{ P(f), P \in \mathbb{R}[X] \}$ the algebra generated by $f$.

And then, we have to find a necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ so that every continuous function defined on $[ \alpha, \beta ]$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of elements of $E$.

So if I am not mistaken, a necessary and sufficient condition is that the function $[\alpha, \beta] \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of elements of E.

But is there better ? Can we find something more simple ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Look up the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for the idea. I've looked it up, and I guess I understand how this can solve my problem. But since here, the algebra is not any algebra, is there a simpler way to find the answer ?

Comment: So, if I understand well, the condition we are looking for is that f must be injective, right ?

Comment: right..........